Adding to a count with a command
I have the following command:
\newcommand{\addtonewcount}[2]{\advance\#1 #2\relax}

#1 is the name of the count and #2 is the degree to which one wants to add to the count.
The command is returning an error. How can this be resolved?
Here's a fuller example:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\addtonewcount}[2]{\advance\#1 #2\relax}

\begin{document}
\newcount\testcountone
\addtonewcount{testcountone}{7}
\end{document}


not so sure about your \#1...

\advance #1 ... and then \addtonewcount\testcount{7}. But why aren't you using LaTeX counters here?

A count (as in \newcount) looks like a command name.  A  counter (as in \newcounter) looks like a label, altough (for example} the counter page is also the count \c@page.  Both point to count registers (in this case \count0).

\advance\#1 would advance the counter \# by 1 if \# was defined to be a count register.

#1 in the macro body when you are defining a macro is the place where actual parameter is inserted when the macro is used and processed. On the other hand, \#1 is a control sequence \# followed by the token 1. This is totally different thing. If you really want to convert a name to the control sequence \name (read already in a parameter) then you must to use \csname ...\endcsname pair of TeX primitives.
Your definition should be:
\def\addtonewcount#1#2{\advance \csname#1\endcsname by#2\relax}

Note that \csname...\endcsname are expandable TeX primitives and \advance TeX primitive works at the main processor level and it reads its parameters after expansion. So, you needn't to use \expandafter TeX primitive in this case.
Note2: the by is optional keyword of the \advance primitive. I am using this in my macros in order to increase the readability of the macro code. We needn't to spare TeX memory in these cases nowadays. It was important 40 years ago wen TeX was created.

Here is the definition of \addtocounter
\addtocounter:
macro:#1#2->\@ifundefined {c@#1}{\@nocounterr {#1}}{\global \advance \csname c@#1\endcsname #2\relax }

It first checks if counter #1 is defined and, if so, add #2 to it.
